# How can I reduce the complexity of my mongo query using some sort of "lookup" mechanism?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, aggregate

I am trying to write a mongo query for some data that contains only the ZIP code the person belongs to.

Here is a sample data set:

```
[
    {
        "name" : "Person1",
        "zip" : "zip12"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Person2",
        "zip" : "zip22"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Person3",
        "zip" : "zip13"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Person4",
        "zip" : "zip32"
    }
]
```

I am trying to add fields to the data so that I can query them based on the state rather than the zip code alone. I would also like to include that data in the final result (state name I mean) as that provides a little more meaning to the data rather than just the zip code, which most people will not be familiar with.

My current implementation is as follows:

```
var state1 = ["zip11", "zip12", "zip13"]
var state2 = ["zip21", "zip22", "zip23"]
var state3 = ["zip31", "zip32", "zip33"]
// many more states

db.collection_name.aggregate([
    {$addFields : {"State" : {$cond : [{$in : ["$zip", state1]}, "State1", {$cond : [{$in : ["$zip", state2]}, "State2", "State3"]}]}}},
    {$match : {"State" : "State1"}}
])
```

While this does work, it generates a rather nasty looking nested conditional statement that I would rather do without. It also makes it hard to include new states to the list as it not only involves creating a new list of zips for a state but also requires updating the query itself.

I was wondering if there was a way to loop through all the list of the states (say, if it was defined as a 2-D array or something similar to a map, which would make the query more reliable in case of more additions to the states list.

I also might have to include other fields for this data based on the zip along, city name, for example or geographic region. What might be the best way to achieve this in mongo?

I am relatively new to mongo so please do excuse any inefficiencies in the query itself or any oversight of the obvious. Thanks!